# how to Disable SSL v3 in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, python-3.6

For some reason, it seems that my python3 code keeps connecting via SSLV3:

```
import socket, ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1) #also tried ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED      #also tried ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_default_certs()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
domain = 'remote.domain.com'
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=domain)
ssl_sock.connect((domain, 443))
```

I've tried all four combinations mentioned in the comment (lines 3+4) but I still get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1093, in connect
     self._real_connect(addr, False)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1084, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
     self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:749)
```

SSL version:

```
`>>>ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`

'OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017'
```

I'm not sure if the ssllabs test will work since this domain only accessible via VPN. Trying to get that info now though.

This might be an issue with my openSSL (ref: https://superuser.com/questions/109213/how-do-i-list-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-offers):

```
:~ rabdelaz$ ./test_ciphers 
Obtaining cipher list from OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016.
Testing ADH-SEED-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing SEED-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ADH-AES256-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA...NO (14094410)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing AES256-SHA...NO (14094410)
Testing ADH-AES128-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA...NO (14094410)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing AES128-SHA...NO (14094410)
Testing ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ADH-DES-CBC-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing EXP-ADH-DES-CBC-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ADH-RC4-MD5...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing EXP-ADH-RC4-MD5...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing DES-CBC3-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing DES-CBC-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing EXP-DES-CBC-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing RC4-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing RC4-MD5...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing EXP-RC4-MD5...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing DES-CBC3-MD5...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing DES-CBC-MD5...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing RC2-CBC-MD5...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing EXP-RC4-MD5...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing RC4-MD5...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing NULL-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing NULL-MD5...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
```

this is probably more relevant:

```
>>> for c in context.get_ciphers():
...   print(c['name'])
... 
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA
DH-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA
DH-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA
DH-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA
DH-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA
AES256-GCM-SHA384
AES128-GCM-SHA256
AES256-SHA256
AES256-SHA
AES128-SHA256
AES128-SHA
CAMELLIA256-SHA
CAMELLIA128-SHA
```

ok here's what's going on (i replaced my ciphers from above into the test_ciphers script):

```
:~ rabdelaz$ ./test_ciphers 
Testing ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA...NO (no ciphers available)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA...NO (no ciphers available)
Testing ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA...NO (no ciphers available)
Testing ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA...NO (no ciphers available)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA...NO (14094410)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing DH-RSA-AES256-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-DSS-AES256-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA...NO (no ciphers available)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA...NO (no ciphers available)
Testing ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA...NO (no ciphers available)
Testing ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA...NO (no ciphers available)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA...NO (14094410)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing DH-RSA-AES128-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-DSS-AES128-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
Testing DH-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
Testing AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (no cipher match)
Testing AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing AES256-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing AES256-SHA...NO (14094410)
Testing AES128-SHA256...NO (no cipher match)
Testing AES128-SHA...NO (14094410)
Testing CAMELLIA256-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
Testing CAMELLIA128-SHA...NO (no cipher match)
```

Comment: Can you append your question with your OpenSSL version (`ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`) and what SSL/TLS suites your `remote.domain.com` supports (you can run a full test using: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=remote.domain.com )

Comment: that output is showing a different openssl version. might need to figure out how to force my test to use python's openssl

Comment: Make sure your `test_ciphers` script's *shabang* points to the Python version you use with your socket test.

Comment: good point. how do i find python's openssl?

Comment: Whichever Python interpreter gave you `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` as `'OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017'` (whatever command you used to open that Python shell) is the one you should be using, primarily for consistency. If you're mixing versions you'll be chasing ghosts for a long time.